# Clearing background color of UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uitableview

I loading all data in UITableView section. 
i getting result of above screen. I want to remove black patch(background color) of table cell.
For that i write following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell setOpaque:NO];
NSDictionary *name = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
[cell.textLabel setText:[name objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

and my nib file is [image]

still i give same result. This code and nib setting worked fine on iPhone simulator but not in iPhone. 
Please why this happen, where i m going to wrong way?
How i remove this problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try to change the property Background, in your nib, make it clear color or whitecolor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Background of View, in your nib, make it clear Color or white Color

also try

in method CellForRowAtIndexPath, like tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

hi RRB

You have to set clearColor of your tableView.backgroundColor run time **not in xib**.